# error: value "5.1.2" for key "Version" in group "Desktop Entry" is not a known version

Tags: .desktop

I have built the latest version of Paraview from source and I am trying to add the desktop file to the dash.

Running

```
sudo desktop-file-install /opt/ParaView5.1.2/Applications/ParaView/paraview.desktop
```

Produces the error

```
/usr/share/applications/paraview.desktop: error: value "5.12" for key "Version" in group "Desktop Entry" is not a known version
Error on file "/opt/ParaView5.1.2/Applications/ParaView/paraview.desktop": Failed to validate the created desktop file
```

The desktop file is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=5.1.2
Type=Application
Name=ParaView
Comment=Parallel visualization application
TryExec=paraview
Icon=paraview
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Version` entry in a `.desktop` file doesn't refer to the version of the target program. It's the version of the desktop file specification that this desktop file conforms to. As explained in the [Freedesktop.org specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html) (emphasis mine):

> Version of the Desktop Entry Specification that the desktop entry conforms with. Entries that confirm with this version of the specification should use 1.0. **Note that the version field is not required to be present.**

So, most importantly, you can just remove the `version` entry, it isn't needed. If you really want it though, it will have to be a valid desktop specification version like `1.0`.